# How does server binding URI pattern to a particular Java class?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jax-rs

I have my rest class below.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/users")
public class UserRestService { 
    @GET
    public Response getUser() { 
        return Response.status(200).entity("getUser is called").build(); 
    }
}
```

I dont know how does server mapping this /users uri pattern with this UserRestService.java file.Do we need to configure in web configuration...?

**My question:** How it is invoking UserRestService.java when /users URI pattern is matching?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your jax-ws servlet is set to respond to particular url in your application like a one follows

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>
                  com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet
            </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: ok i understood. how /hello pattern identifying my resource file name(controller). do we need to mention anyting in WSSpringServlet??. Pls clarify me...

Comment: it will route all request like http://localhost:8080/{your applicatinon}/hello to WSSpringServlet. so your controller will be invoked at url http://localhost:8080/{your applicatinon}/hello/users

Comment: @Saravanan you need to anotate each controller with different name, something like @Path("/department")

Answer (score 1):

There is a class `javax.ws.rs.core.Application;` which you need to extend (atleast I did this) in order to register your *JaxRs Resource URI* and provide the corresponding info in *web.xml* like :-

```
public class ExtendedClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(UserRestService.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

in web.xml :-

```
    <servlet>
        <description>
        JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>

<param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>

<param-value>package.name.ExtendedClass</param-value>

</init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a `REST` based architecture everything is a resource. A resource is accessed via a common interface based on the HTTP standard methods `(e.g., POST, GET, PUT or DELETE)`. And it's `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher` servlet class mentioned in `web.xml` of your web application that enlist all `JAX-RS` root resources and providers.

And with the `/*` url-pattern all resources will be passed to `RESTeasy` servlet.

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
  </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You will be wondering how `RESTeasy` came to know about my class annotated with `@Path`, so there is another configuration that let `RESTeasy` know about your resources which you have to mention in your `web.xml` i.e.

```
 <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

So when request comes from  `/users` then `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher` serrvlet identifies the URI path that a resource class or class method will serve requests for and call it which is `UserRestService` in your case.

Hope it helps :)